# Queue multiple PackageInstallRequest to be installed in order?

Tags: tooling-api, package, package-install

I can create multiple `PackageInstallRequest` records via the Tooling API to queue the installation of multiple packages, but the packages are installed in an indeterminate order. Some of the packages I'm trying to install depend on other packages, so some of the installations fail because the dependencies haven't been installed yet, even if I originally create the records in the correct order. Is there any way to get them to install in order so that I don't need to wait for each installation to finish before queueing the next?

Comment: Are you using sfdx?

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm trying to do it all on platform. I'm calling the tooling api from apex.